# Combine results from two REST endpoints?

Tags: c#, .net, api, rest

I'm new to C# and REST api.

So, I have endpoint A that takes city name or city name and company ID (Unique Id, can be list of ID) as request to return the the company information. Like company name, address, contact.

Then I have endpoint B that takes in the same request and returns different information. like type of business structure, number of employee and revenue.

Now, I need a third endpoint to return Company name, address, contact, type of business structure, number of employee and revenue.

What's a better way to implement this? At first, I thought just call endpoint A, use the returned company Ids to call endpoint B. but I'm not sure how to retain the data like company name, address, contact.

Another way I can think is to merge the two results based on the company ID. Is there a easy way to do with JSON data?

Comment: This question isn't likely to produce a "correct" answer. There are lots of ways you can slice your API, with pros and cons to each approach. Think about the business needs introduced by your domain, and the Reasons For Change associated with those needs. For example, does some company data have different permissions requirements to access? Is some data queried far more often than other data? Is it worth introducing OData capabilities into your API so the consuming request can specify what it wants?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior. Thanks for the comment. No permission involved. Main goal here is to create a new endpoint that combines the two data set based on the company Id. I'm just trying to get some ideas of how to implement this since I'm new to REST and have a little knowledge with C#

Comment: One option would be to pass the IDs to both endpoints (concurrently), await their results, put their results into Dictionaries keyed by the ID, and then for all the IDs you started with merge the results into an object that has both models for a given ID. But I'd wonder what the utility is in an endpoint whose sole purpose is to combine data from other endpoints. Why can't the API consumers do the same thing, without requiring any changes server-side?

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
/companies?city={city}
/companies?id[]={id1}&id[]={id2}&id[]={id3}...
/companies/{id}
/companies/{id}/profile
/companies/{id}/structure
```

I removed city name from the second because the id is unique.

If you need anything more complex than this, then probably you need an URI query language or use the SEARCH method to send more complex search expression for example in JSON, SQL, LD fragments, etc... or some sort of custom DSL.

Comment: Sorry I'm still a bit confused. Are you saying use the id to query the "profile" and "structure" and then combine them?

Comment: @Michael For the `/companies/{id}` you got a JSON something like `{profile:{...},structure:{...}}` and problem solved. Or you can have a flat JSON for all 3 if there are overlapping properties. There is a HTTP header, which can describe verbosity, but it is rarely used. I don't even remember its name. I would rather make a new resource instead of using it.